# Getting the size of a function in C

Tags: c

Assume this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a(){
 int b = 5;
 return b;
}

int main ()
{
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
  return 0;
}
```

Above prints `1`. What does that mean?

I know when `sizeof` is used on a struct, it gets the total size of the data types within it in bytes. But what does it mean when it's used on a function?

Edit:

What if I do `sizeof(a()))` instead of `sizeof(a))`. Now it's printing `4` which is the size of the return type, is this the correct way? how is it not undefined?

Answer (score 3):

Applying the `sizeof` operator to a function is a constraint violation.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This constraint is specified in section 6.5.3.4p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `sizeof` operator:

> **The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type** or an incomplete  type,  to  the  parenthesized  name 
>   of  such  a  type,  or  to  an  expression  that designates  a 
>   bit-field  member.   The `_Alignof` operator  shall  not  be  applied 
>   to  a function type or an incomplete type.

Comment: What if I do `sizeof(a()))` instead of `sizeof(a))`. Now it's printing `4` which is the size of the return type, is this the correct way? how is it not undefined?

Comment: @Alex `sizeof(a()))` is valid because `a()` has type `int` which is the return type of the function.  *"is this the correct way?"* to do what?

Comment: printing `size_t` with `%d` also invokes UB. `%p` must be used instead

Comment: @phuclv `%p` is for pointers.  `%zu` is for `size_t`.

Comment: @dbush yeah, I mistyped `%p` instead of `%zu`